# How can I create a dynamic YTD anchor in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, date-arithmetic

Does anyone know if it is possible to have a calculated field that would query YTD and dynamically set the anchor for the last day of the previous month?

My data is coming from Google Analytics, so this is just a very standard Date YTD field.

Image example: http://screencast.com/t/oRiYnr6ZDHK

Changing this anchor each month in dozens of places is very tedious.

My thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

date(dateadd('day',-1,datetrunc('month',now())))

starting from the inside out:
-datetrunc('month',now()) - truncates the current datetime at the month level.
-dateadd('day',-1,... - subtract 1 day to get the last day of the previous month.
-date(... - convert final datetime to just a date.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It works perfectly in regards to pulling the correct date, but I have been unable to get it to work as a (date) filter. 

I created the calculation 'Dynamic YTD' and dragged it to my filter shelf but it still pulls everything YTD (not 2/28/2015). 

Any thoughts?

Thanks again.

Comment: Create a new calculated field, set above calc_field < date_column, drag to filter shelf and filter on 'true'.